# Confuse about fail2ban behavior with firewallD in Centos 7

Tags: fail2ban, firewalld

I was using fail2ban/iptables in a Centos 6 server.
I moved to Centos 7 and now I am using fail2ban/firewallD (installed by Webmin/Virtualmin with their defaults)

These are `cat /var/log/maillog | grep "disconnect from unknown"` screen shots
[image]
[image]
[image]
`cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep Ban`  only displays

> 2019-10-27 16:52:22,975 fail2ban.actions        [8792]: NOTICE  [proftpd] Ban 111.225.204.32

Furthermore `tailf /var/log/fail2ban.log` displays several "already banned" of the same IP.  In this case fail2ban, after `maxretry` is reached it tries to ban the IP.
[image]

Here are my configurations (partial), I left them as they were by defaults but changed bantimes.

**jail.local**

> [postfix]
>   enabled  = true
>   port     = smtp,465,submission
>   bantime = -1
>
> [postfix-sasl]
>   enabled  = true
>   port     = smtp,465,submission,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s
>   bantime = -1
>
> [dovecot]
>   enabled = true
>   port    = pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve
>   bantime = -1

**jail.conf**

> [DEFAULT]
>   findtime = 600
>   maxretry = 5
>   backend = auto
>   filter = %(__name__)s
>   port = 0:65535
>   banaction = iptables-multiport
>   banaction_allports = iptables-allports
>   action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%    > (port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
>   action = %(action_)s

**jail.d/00-firewalld.conf**

> [DEFAULT]
>   banaction = firewallcmd-ipset

These files exist: *action.d/firewallcmd-ipset.conf* and *filter.d/postfix.conf*

`firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules`

> ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -m set
>   --match-set fail2ban-default src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
>   ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
>   ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 10000 -m set --match-set fail2ban-webmin-auth src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
>   ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh,sftp -m set --match-set fail2ban-ssh-ddos src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

After manually running
`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='193.56.28.0/24' reject"`
and
`firewall-cmd --reload`  this output of `tailf /var/log/fail2ban.log`
[image]
stopped.

How can I get all those IPs banned after they reach `maxretry` value?
Would they be banned forever despite service restart or reload?

**Edit 1:**
From fail2ban.log with action=firewalld-cmd ipset
[image]

From fail2ban.log with action=iptables-allports
[image]

**Edit 2:**
It seems (I guess) something is flushing configurations (I guess it would be Webmin) because after a while I start getting error logs like `failed to execute ban jail 'dovecot' action iptables-allports` so I am trying this: 
in actions.d created banning.conf

```
[Definition]      

actionban = /usr/bin/firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='<IP>' reject"; ; /usr/bin/firewall-cmd --reload
```

and at jail.local

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-multiport 
            banning
```

But I get `Error in action definition banning`
I know this is not a solution.
Before moving the server I was using fail2ban/iptables (not firewalld) for years not having to pay attention beyond default settings.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get all those IPs banned after they reach maxretry value?

Your issue has probably nothing with `maxretry` etc. 
If you see `[jail] Ban 192.0.2.1` and several `[jail] 192.0.2.1 already banned` messages hereafter (especially after some minutes after the "Ban" message for same Jail/IP), this means only that your banning action (firewalld) does not work at all (after ban, the intruder-IP is still able to repeat its attempts).

In the last time we had certain issues with that (especially with combination firewalld + CentOS) - see for example https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1609 as well as related firewalld issue - https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/515.
So check your native net-filter (iptables, etc), if you see some (white-listing established traffic) rules before fail2ban chains, it looks like your configuration is not fail2ban (or whatever banning-system) capable... here may be the answer for you - https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2503#issuecomment-533105500.

Here is another similar issue with an example excerpt illustrating "wrong iptables rule that bypass fail2ban" - https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2545#issuecomment-543347684

In this case:

- either switch the backend of firewalld (as suggested above);
- or switch the banaction of fail2ban to something native (iptables/ipset/etc).
- or even add still one action dropping or killing active established connection of the banned IP (using something like tcpkill, killcx, ss etc).

---

**UPDATE 1**

jail.local example:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports

[postfix-sasl]
enabled = true
[dovecot]
enabled = true
...
```

If after fail2ban reload you'd still see some IP making attempts after ban and `already banned` in fail2ban.log, provide log-excerpt of fail2ban **by the first ban** or else some possible errors around (because `already banned` is too late and does not help at all).
If no errors are there, provide output of `iptables -nL`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with fail2ban/firewallD It seems some things were missed during Centos 7/Webmin installation (by Contabo). By default, action for proftpd, dovecot++ is firewallcmd-ipset. For this I found `ERROR   ipset add fail2ban-proftpd 222.182.57.235 timeout -1 -exist -- stderr: 'ipset v7.1: The set with the given name does not exist\n'`  I changed some actions to iptables-allports and I got `ERROR   iptables -w -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-default[ \t]' -- stdout: ''` and `iptables -w -X f2b-default -- stderr: "iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target f2b-default':No such file or d`

Comment: Your screenshots show only after effects, but fail2ban (jail.local) configuration seems to be wrong: either you should set `banaction` only or if set `action`/`action_` value, you have to specify all expected parameters, like it is set in DEFAULT - see [jail.conf#L174](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/5cf064a1126416b1143ea3925b290e824355170e/config/jail.conf#L174).
Or provide excerpt of `fail2ban-client -d` for jail that not working.

Comment: I only added `bantime=-1` to default jail.local. Here is the output of  dovecot, proftpd and postfix-sasl https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MDVkU0tC0FuW51eJmsNaoR4pWhAf1l3tYf6_FwLLwDk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well do you see `... 'name', 'default'` in output for each jail?
This means you have not correctly set `action` (it misses parameter name), so read my second comment attentively: either use `banaction = firewalld-ipset` or `action = firewalld-ipset[...all-parameters-action-needed...]` like in https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/5cf064a1126416b1143ea3925b290e824355170e/config/jail.conf#L174

Comment: I'm still stuck. I added some info to the DOC: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MDVkU0tC0FuW51eJmsNaoR4pWhAf1l3tYf6_FwLLwDk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: After jail.local changes no more "already banned" in log file.  I found 1 (only 1) dovecot "Found" 2 mins after banned and another protfpd 1 second after ban. I added some info to https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MDVkU0tC0FuW51eJmsNaoR4pWhAf1l3tYf6_FwLLwDk/edit?usp=sharing Reject IP /24 ranges were added manually by me during this period

Comment: During this period I wrote a script to compare IPs from lines containing "disconnected from unknown" of maillog with already manually banned IPs to get a list of new IPs that should be banned (and the number of access attempts). Comparison is done over the first 9 IP digits. Then I manually executed a command to reject the range x.x.x.0/24 Today I found 160.20.109.x was not banned because attempts were varying "x" not to reach max attempts. Not sure if I have to care about that and what to do whitin fail2ban.

Comment: Today I got a report with a unique IP trying to connect 626 times (more than `maxretry` attempts during `findtime`)  so I ran `cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep "already"` and got again several new "already banned" records but the in the day Nov 12 when I made the last jail.local suggested changes. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/19HExhAsbn0Z84qlk3vLn4KIfXO9hDoul9GIEEjmoi0Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Still again: `already banned` is an after effect and provide no info why it is happened (just a signal that IP is already banned but still makes attempt)... so take a look above (for some errors if IP gets banned first time)... the reason for that as already described: either banaction fails (errors in log), or net-filter subsystem targeting by banaction does not work properly, or something bothers here (something is flushing rules, some white-listing rules are there, e.g. for established connections, etc pp)

Comment: In fail2ban.log file I have `2019-11-16 10:48:26,183 fail2ban.actions        [1707]: ERROR   Failed to execute ban jail 'postfix-sasl' action 'iptables-multiport' info 'CallingMap({'ipjailmatches': <function <lambda> at 0x7fe5f0ff08c0>, 'matches':` I already had added to my question as a screenshot. I see other old answers you made about imap3. `jail.conf` has some imap3 ports but it is set in /etc/services.  Continues....

Comment: I don't know what else to check so, would a fail2ban reinstall surpass the problems? As said it was installed automatically when installed Webmin/Virtualmin (by a module it has). According to virtualmin.com/comment/800250#comment-800250 it can be removed deleting that module. Maybe doing that and then yum install fail2ban would be enough. I asked Webmin folks about this issue more than 10 days ago with no answer. On the other hand I guess I could add an action(run command) to reject "banned" IP via firewall-cmd. Today after restart f2b I got a IP Ban without error. Flushing confs? Don't see wh

Comment: 7 hours ago I deleted the Webmin module to manage fail2ban. I find strange that no IP has to be banned since then so I cannot tell you if there are errors. Before then some IPs had been banned by f2b

Comment: Well, after writting that ... 12:39 `Ban 94.102.57.169` 19:27 `94.102.57.169 already banned` I don't know where the error is. jail.conf hasn't been edited and [Default] in jail.local contains only what you suggested and services only have different bantimes

Comment: still again: there could be few issues only to cause that...<br/>
either an error in banning action (check fail2ban.log); or whitelisting rules in firewall/net-filter (e.g. for established connections); or flush of f2b-rules made from some external service (so IP is still banned in fail2ban, but no rules in firewall anymore).

Comment: As said this is an almost new LAMP install. I don't know what could be flushing firewall rules, if that so. I'm thinking in reinstalling fail2ban-firewalld-0.9.7 and fail2ban-server-0.9.7. That will be useless if there's something outside f2b flushing firewall rules. The other option is to hire you to find out what happens.

Comment: I would like to put the `jail.local` highlighted but the edit queue is full now, as usual to me...

Comment: I also would like to suggest to put the SSH and Postfix abilitations in dedicated `jail.d/sshd.conf` files instead of putting everything in `jail.local`. But the edit queue is full now...